# Shorthand PHP Environment Variables

Tags: php, azure, if-statement, environment, shorthand

I'm looking to transition from Localhost to Dev to East/West staging environments to production without having to change the PHP files, but I don't think my code is correct and it could be my shorthand, I'm new to this.

What I'm hoping to do is say, if localhost then else if dev, else if staging east, else if staging west, else if production. Maybe there's a better way of doing this?

If it helps, I'm using Apache as my local host and Azure in dev/staging/production, I'd use both but I don't have access to Azure.

```
<?php
$thisPage = "navigation";
define('URL_ROOT',
            getenv('DEV_SERVER') ?
                'http://localhost/Site/' :
                'dev.website.net' :
                'http://website-east.website.net/' :
                'http://website-west.website.net/' :
                'http://production-website.com/'
);
?>
```

Comment: Hopefully my edit makes it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: What output do you expect to get from `getenv('DEV_SERVER')` for each of the 5 servers?

Comment: @AbraCadaver You are correct, OP has too many arguments for using the ternary operator. I think they would benefit from a `switch(){}` statement otherwise things will get ugly.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for editing it, it's more readable now. I have the DEV_SERVER defined in Apache for my local host. My thought was that if it's on Azure and can't find my local host, it would go to the dev.website.net version, and if it can't find that, then go to the website-east and so on... I'm trying to figure out if I can push to multiple environments without having to always edit the PHP file for each new environment. I'm not sure how to use a switch(){} but I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: @user2966325 a `switch` will likely be the cleanest solution and it will help you figure out what to do in each situation. I'll post an answer with it's usage :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our comments from above, here you go:

```
switch(strtolower(getenv('DEV_SERVER')))
{
    case 'localhost':
        define('URL_ROOT', 'http://localhost/Site/');
        break;
    case 'dev':
        define('URL_ROOT', 'dev.website.net');
        break;
    case 'east':
        define('URL_ROOT', 'http://website-east.website.net/');
        break;
    case 'west':
        define('URL_ROOT', 'http://website-west.website.net/');
        break;
    case 'prod':
        define('URL_ROOT', 'http://production-website.com/');
        break;
    default:
        die('Environment not defined!!');
}
```

If you can then I would recommend setting a generic environment variable name such as `getenv('SERVER_ENVIRONMENT')` and use that in your `switch()` because `DEV_SERVER` implies that it's T/F only and each server besides dev would be set to F.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to set a generic environment variable so it's not just T/F.